# how to put a varilabe in 2d array in C

Tags: c, stdout

I want to decalre on 2d array, but I want to put a vrailbe into the declartaion

```
#define MAX_SIZE 512
char* FWdir;
int main()
{
 getFwDIR(FWdir);  //--> put In FWdir path example: /opt/fw1
 char arr [][MAX_SIZE] = {
 FWdir,"-t","arg"
};

}
```

try to iterate over arr in ,didnt get the /opt/fw1 , instead I got an adress

I expoected to get

if I will print arr I waill get

/opt/fw1 -t arg...
insead I get
"someoutput" -t arg

Comment: Show the implementation of `getFwDir()`, the problem is there (you need to pass a pointer to  `FWdir`: `getFwDIR(&FWdir);` in order to alter the original pointer)

Comment: you need to show a [mcve]

Comment: `FWdir` will be a null pointer. There's nothing that `getFwDIR` can do to its argument to make it not a null pointer.

Comment: You cannot initialize arrays with a pointer in C. Unless the array happens to be an array of pointers, which isn't the case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here.

The first is you are passing the pointer `FWdir` to `getFwDIR()`, but `FWdir` is NULL, so `getFwDIR()` has nowhere to store the path. In its current formulation of `getFwDIR(char *)`, that function cannot dynamically allocate memory for the path either.

The second is that you are attempting to write the contents of the string `FWdir` directly into the array `arr`, but that is not how strings work in C.

On the first point, you have two obvious options:

1. Rewrite `getFwDIR()` to accept a pointer to a pointer `getFwDIR(char **)`, and dynamically allocate space for the path in that function:

```c
int getFwDIR(char **p_path)
{
  ...
  *p_path = malloc(MAXIMUM_PATH_LENGTH + 1);
  ... // Proceed to get the path
}

...
int main(void)
{
  getFwDIR(&FWdir);  //--> put In FWdir path example: /opt/fw1
...
}
```

But, this does leave the issue of freeing the memory later on.

2. Make `FWdir` a string with definite length, and pass that to `getFwDIR()`:

```c
#define MAX_SIZE 512
char FWdir[MAX_SIZE];
```

Since you have, in `arr`, effectively limited the path length to 511 characters anyway I would go for the second option, which is easier and safer.

On the second point, you also have two clear options:

1. Declare the 2d array first, and pass the first element to `getFwDIR()`:

```c
 char arr [][MAX_SIZE] =
 {
   "","-t","arg"
 };
 getFwDIR(arr[0]);  //--> put In FWdir path example: /opt/fw1
```

In this one, you do not need `FWdir`.

2. Copy `FWdir` into the array *after* initialisation:

```c
 char FWdir[MAX_SIZE];
 getFwDIR(FWdir);  //--> put In FWdir path example: /opt/fw1
 char arr [][MAX_SIZE] =
 {
   "","-t","arg"
 };
 strncpy(arr[0], FWdir, sizeof(arr[0]));
```